# Deep learning model performance heavily dependent on initial model weights

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation, randomness, weight-initialization

While my deep learning model is quite robust to randomness coming from train/test data-splits, it is not robust to initial model weights.

How should I go about this?
Also, I'd greatly appreciate it if you direct me to the right materials.

Comment: You could look up the "Lottery Ticket Hypothesis". It could be that making your network several times bigger will make it more robust to the choice of initial weights, especially if you are using ReLU activations. Conceptually, the idea is that training a bigger network is more or less like training a bunch of different networks starting at different initializations, and it will also be more robust to cells dying due to zero activations.

Answer (score 1):

Without any details on the model, it is very hard to say what the problem is.
Problem 1: Your model does not converge: Most likely variation due to random weights is not the issue.
Problem 2: Your model performance fluctuates by 0.5-2%. This is normal.

Either way, you could add batch-normalization to stabilize training.
You might also try a different initialization, e.g., see the related work of "Correlated Initialization for Correlated Data" by Schneider (2022) for a recent paper on initialization (Disclaimer: I am the author of the paper).